# Unity C# - Car Spawning: Issues with Collisions and Behavior

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing a car game in Unity and facing some challenges with car spawning. Here's the setup:

I have 10 SpawnPoints arranged in a line, each at a fixed distance from the other. The goal is to generate cars from these SpawnPoints with the following characteristics:

**Random Speed:** Each car should spawn with a random speed.
**Random Time Interval:** Cars should spawn at random time intervals within a specified range.
**Avoid Collisions:** Cars should not collide with each other.
Here's a snippet of my current spawning script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] spawnLocations;
    public GameObject[] gameObjectsToSpawn;
    public int maxCarsToSpawn = 3; // Maximum number of cars to spawn simultaneously.
    public float minSpawnInterval = 2.0f;
    public float maxSpawnInterval = 5.0f;
    public float objectLifetime = 10.0f;
    public float minSpeed = 5.0f; // Minimum speed for the cars.
    public float maxSpeed = 15.0f; // Maximum speed for the cars.

    private Dictionary<Transform, float> lastSpawnTimeByLocation = new Dictionary<Transform, float>();


    private List<int> usedSpawnPoints = new List<int>(); // Keep track of used spawn points.

    private void Start()
    {
        // Start spawning cars using a coroutine
        StartCoroutine(SpawnRandomCars());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnRandomCars()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Calculate a random time interval
            float spawnInterval = Random.Range(minSpawnInterval, maxSpawnInterval);

            // Wait for the random time interval
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnInterval);

            // Determine how many cars to spawn simultaneously (up to maxCarsToSpawn)
            int numCarsToSpawn = Random.Range(1, maxCarsToSpawn + 1);

            // Shuffle the spawn locations to randomize which ones are used
            ShuffleSpawnLocations();

            for (int i = 0; i < numCarsToSpawn; i++)
            {
                if (usedSpawnPoints.Count >= spawnLocations.Length)
                {
                    // All spawn points have been used; reset the used spawn points list.
                    usedSpawnPoints.Clear();
                }

                int randomCarIndex = Random.Range(0, gameObjectsToSpawn.Length);

                int randomLocationIndex;
                do
                {
                    // Choose a random spawn location that hasn't been used recently
                    randomLocationIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnLocations.Length);
                } while (usedSpawnPoints.Contains(randomLocationIndex) && Time.time - lastSpawnTimeByLocation[spawnLocations[randomLocationIndex]] < 2f);

                usedSpawnPoints.Add(randomLocationIndex);

                lastSpawnTimeByLocation[spawnLocations[randomLocationIndex]] = Time.time;

                // Instantiate the chosen car at the selected location
                GameObject spawnedCar = Instantiate(gameObjectsToSpawn[randomCarIndex], spawnLocations[randomLocationIndex].position, Quaternion.identity);

                // Set the speed of the car
                float carSpeed = Random.Range(minSpeed, maxSpeed);
                Rigidbody carRigidbody = spawnedCar.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                carRigidbody.velocity = spawnedCar.transform.forward * carSpeed;


                // Destroy the spawned car after the specified lifetime
                Destroy(spawnedCar, objectLifetime);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ShuffleSpawnLocations()
    {
        // Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm to randomize spawn locations.
        for (int i = 0; i < spawnLocations.Length; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, spawnLocations.Length);
            Transform temp = spawnLocations[i];
            spawnLocations[i] = spawnLocations[randomIndex];
            spawnLocations[randomIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
```

However, cars are currently colliding with each other, and the spawning behavior is not as expected.

I'm seeking advice on how to modify the script to prevent collisions between spawned cars and improve the overall spawning behavior. Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want cars to collide with each other, you can make use of [Layer-based collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)